# How to use Google Spreadsheets functions inside Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

so I need to find the ROW / COLUMN of the value I type, for example in spreadsheet I would just type =MATCH(key) inside a cell, how would I use those same functions inside node.js?

I searched online for an hour, but nothing came up. I'm using the googleapis v4 for spreadsheet.

Comment: Wouldn't it be [this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)?  Or, if using the nodejs-specific API, [this one](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#node.js_1).

Comment: Yea, i've seen these functions, but how do I use them to use a formula inside the script?

Comment: Well, your question said you just wanted to get a row/column value and that's what these APIs do.  If you have a more specific question than that, then please edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do.